# Decompose Poisson random variable as sum of Poisson random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X,Y$ are independent Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, then $X+Y$ is Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$. I am wondering whether the converse if true, given a poisson random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$, can we always decompose it into independent poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ such that there sum is the given random variable?

Comment: I am almost sure that on given sufficiently 'small' probability space where $Z\sim Poiss(\lambda)$ is given with $\lambda =\lambda_1+\lambda_2$, it is impossible to construct $X\sim Poiss(\lambda_1)$, without any further requirements.

Comment: For sufficiently large sample space it is always possible: look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506891/

Comment: @NCh Excellent answer! Thank you

Comment: @NCh : What's this about "sufficiently large"? See my answer below. There's no such hypothesis.

Comment: Sufficiently large - i.e. there exists all the variables you states without any proof of their existence. Please construct such $X$ on $\Omega=\{0,1,2,\ldots \}$ with $\mathcal F=2^\Omega$ and $P(\{k\})=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$, for $W(\omega)=\omega$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom This answer does not answer the question, as well as the answer below. Since the answer to the original question seems to be "No", the answer will be an example where it is proved that one cannot decompose a given Poisson r.v. on a given probability space into a sum of independent Poisson r.v.'s.

Comment: If the question is taken to mean that the probability space whose underlying set is the domain of the two independent random variables must be the SAME probability space with which one started, then the answer appears to be that in some cases it cannot be done. But if the space one starts with is allowed to be a subspace or a quotient space of some larger space on which the two independent random variables are defined, then it can always be done.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $W\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda).$

Suppose $0<\lambda_1 <\lambda,$ and let $\lambda_2 = \lambda - \lambda_1.$

Let $p = \dfrac{\lambda_1}\lambda = \dfrac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.$

Let $X\mid W \sim\operatorname{Binomial}(W,p),$ i.e. this is the number of successes in $W$ independent trials with probability $p$ of success on each trial. Let $Y= W-X.$ Then $Y\mid W \sim\operatorname{Binomial}(W,1-p).$

Given all of this, one can conclude that

- $W=X+Y.$
- $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_1).$
- $Y \sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_2).$
- $X,Y$ are independent.

Proving this is a standard exercise. How to do it is a question that has been posted here a number of times.

Comment: Let  $\Omega=\{0,1,2,\ldots \}$ with $\mathcal F=2^\Omega$ and $P(\{k\})=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$ and $W(\omega)=\omega$. Does there exist $X$ as you claim on this probability space?

Comment: @NCh : I take your comment as a criticism of the practice of identifying the theory of probability with what Kolmogorov said it is.

Comment: I don’t really understand how the request to construct a random variable on a given probability space can be perceived as a criticism of the Kolmogorov approach to the axiomatization of probability theory. Perhaps, due to poor language skills, I do not catch any nuances. But in the question it is emphasized that the random variable has already been set somewhere, and it is on this space that it is required to construct the summands. You offer to expand it by introducing extra r.v.'s, without noticing it yourself. This is the only thing I object to. By the way, this is not my downvote.

Comment: Despite this, many thanks for the comment! I realize that the excessive craving for constructions underlying the foundations of probability prevents me from properly appreciating true probabilistic facts.

Comment: @NCh : ok, The question can be construed as wanting the decomposition to be on the same probability space, and in some contexts it might be the most reasonable way to construe it, and possibly that's what was intended.